# Android Touch-Screen Keyboards or Positional Offset for Huge Hands

Tags: android, virtual-keyboard, keyboard, touchscreen, ergonomics

I have ***huge*** hands.

Trying to type or swipe (swype) text on Android devices is an exercise in futility.

My fingers are so big, I can't see which letter I'm going to hit. Whatever part of my finger hits the screen first is rarely the letter I intend, and so the wrong letter gets entered.

I have lots of calluses on my hands, so I can't feel the puny screen too well either.

Is there an Android keyboard where I can specify a positional ***offset*** so that I can make touch-screen typing easier?

In other words, when I try to hit the letter "X", all Android (and Apple for that matter) devices think I'm typing the letter "A".  I want to teach it: "no, you're a bit off, I mean the letter over *THERE!*".

Interestingly, normal application touching and pointing isn't too bad for me... it's just when I need something precise like touching a particular letter that I get poor results.

I would also consider something that provides a positional offset for ALL touch-screen touches.

Root apps are fine.  Free-of-cost is better, but not required.  Open-source is better, but also not required.

Comment: Try [big button keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigbuttons&hl=en)

Comment: Have you tried using a stylus?

Comment: @SteveBarnes The common small styluses are too small to grip when you have big hands, and the big styluses are too inconvenient.

Comment: I doubt such an app exists, but [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey) has a "heat map" that points out your inaccuracies to help you work on your positional offset. Also, try typing in landscape mode where the keys are wider

Answer (score 1):

A look into my list of apps for [Keyboards & Input Methods](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_keyboards) should give you something to select from. Though I've never heard of any providing you with the option to define "offsets", there are some with "bigger keys" available:

**[Big Buttons Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigbuttons)** was already mentioned in the comments. As its name suggests, it features bigger buttons for bigger fingers – with the disadvantage of the keyboard filling more of the screen:

[image: BigButtons] [image: BigButtons]
<sup>*Big Buttons Keyboard* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigbuttons); click images for larger variants)</sup>

An alternative is **[Bauer Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bauerergonomics.easykeyboard)**, which is a mix of "Big Buttons" and "T9" (or rather it looks like that):

[image: Bauer Keyboard] [image: Bauer Keyboard] [image: Bauer Keyboard]
<sup>*Bauer Keyboard (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bauerergonomics.easykeyboard); click images for larger variants)</sup>

From this app's description:

> This is a very user friendly keyboard borne of frustration with the tiny keys on stock keyboards. Bauer Keyboard has larger buttons than the stock keyboard so it's easier to type accurately, even on small screens or with large fingers.
>
> […]
>
> Each keyboard button has nine glyphs. Tap the button for the letter or symbol in the center position. For other letters or symbols, simply put your finger on the center of the button and drag in the direction of the symbol from the center and release.

A third candidate: [Super Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beautifulapps.superkeyboard.free) offers several "compact styles", where again multiple letters share a button so bigger fingers have it easier to hit:

[image: Super Keyboard] [image: Super Keyboard]
<sup>*Super Keyboard* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beautifulapps.superkeyboard.free); click images for larger variants)</sup>

As the app's description puts it: *Large keys! You can even make them taller if you want.*

**[ThickButtons Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thickbuttons)** takes a different approach: it tries to predict which letter you will most likely needing next, and makes *those* bigger:

[image: ThickButtons] [image: ThickButtons] [image: ThickButtons]
<sup>*ThickButtons Keyboard* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thickbuttons); click images for larger variants)</sup>

This should give you something to chose from. There are probably more, but I can't list them all. I've hand-picked some of the best rated here – but have to admit to not having personal experiences with any of them.

Comment: Thank you Izzy! ThickButtons looks like a great possibility.  I hope it has some way to swipe/swype!  I'm still looking for a keyboard with an adjustable positional offset, but these will be meaningful experiments until myself or someone else finds (or creates) one.

Comment: Thought so. As written, I never happened to see one (and by the first link in the answer you can tell I've checked a lot) – but if I do, I hopefully remember to coming back here and report :)

Comment: Thanks again, Izzy.  I'm sure if you find one, you'll remember.  BTW, I seem to remember something at one point that let the user configure where their finger is really pointing.  I can't even remember if it was Android or another OS.

Comment: Your finger runs on Android – and you can configure where it's pointing? Pretty cool stuff that! My fingers still run the old-fashioned way :) Honestly: I rawly remember having read something like that (in context of calibration), but not where. As written: When I remember (or re-find), I hopefully will also remember to update here :)